# Javascript: retrieving contents of label present in li

Tags: javascript

I am newbie to javascript and I am not getting solution to following problem
My code is :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label name = "mv"> Movie1 </label>
        <label name = "sn"> Song1 </label>
        <label name = "ac"> Actor1 </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label name = "mv"> Movie2 </label>
        <label name = "sn"> Song2 </label>
        <label name = "ac"> Actor2 </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to retrieve movie1 song1 and actor1 in first iteration and same way for next.
Someone please help.
Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Why do you have [`name` attributes on `<label>`s?](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/label.html#label-attributes)

Comment: @muistooshort I want to distinguish between label.

Comment: Why not use an attribute that is valid for a `<label>`?

Comment: You need to use document.getElementsByName() or you can check out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GDJTM/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CKeGx/1/)

```
a=document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
console.log(a[0].childNodes[1].innerText);
```

This will give you exactly what you want. 
If you want the second list then use the following

```
console.log(a[0].childNodes[3].innerText);
```

***EDIT***: Somehow Firefox does not take the .innerText attribute. The alternative would be to use

> .textContent

Cross browser compatible. Tested in IE,Chrome, FF

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/CKeGx/2/)

Comment: Check the solution now. This one is better.

Comment: Nice answer. I am new so I was hoping not to use this style.I am sending this info (movie1, song1, actor1) to function. and I want it to be distinguished at the start so that I can send (movie1, song1, actor1) to fun1 and other values to fun2. But this is solving my problem. I think of it but curious about simpler way than this. Thanks for faster response.

Comment: `innerHTML` and this is giving the entire HTML code of li!

Comment: @rps. Have you check the fiddle or code. I am using innerText. Not innerHTML

Comment: the fiddle, I am getting `undefined` for `innerText` in the console. using firefox and when I change it to `innerHTML` it shows the entire html code.

Comment: Just checked it. Good spot. check my edit now

Comment: @AnaMaria +1 perfecto! ( * * )

Comment: @AnaMaria http://jsfiddle.net/z9W3e/ why its not working ?

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/z9W3e/1/

Comment: @AnaMaria, I am getting `undefined` in that fiddle, I suppose `lis.find("li").eq(0).text()` will solve that problem. Guess OP is trying out JQuery now!

Comment: @AnaMaria Hey I tried on IE it was working well but now as I am doing it on firefox. its not working it says a[0] is undefined. I used textContent also.

Comment: If you are talking about my solution then check my edit. If you are talking about jQuery version by Ashok Damani then check this http://jsfiddle.net/z9W3e/2/

Comment: Thanks I forgot to check for all comments.

Answer (score 2):

simple:

```
function getData(){
    var result=[];
    var lis=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var k=0;k<lis.length;k++){
        for(var j=0;j<lis[k].childNodes.length;j++){
            result[k][j]=lis[k].childNodes[j].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

it will return an array, and each element of the array will be another array, and each element of that array will be the value of a label. For example, it might return this:

```
[
    [
        'Great Gatsby',
        'Counting Stars',
        'Lio Decaprio'
    ],
    [
        'Argo',
        'Bangarang',
        'Johnny Depp'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer in multiple way

Answer (score 1):

```
var labels=document.getElementsByTagName("label");
var set=labels.length/3;
var myAry=[];

for(var i=0;i<set;i++){
 var str="";
   for(var j=(i*3);j<(i+1)*3;j++){ 
       str+=labels[j].innerHTML;
   }

 myAry.push(str); // myAry[0]= movie1 song1 actor1, myAry[1]=movie1 song1 actor1
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wsfFh/

Comment: Thanks.It is nice that within a hour  I got the answer

Answer (score -1):

This is easier using jQuery

```
$("li").each(function(){
    var text = "";
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        text += " " + $(this).text() 
    });
    console.log(text)
});
```

Comment: -1 for providing a Jquery solution which really does not jQuery. Neither it is easier nor advisable.

Comment: @AnaMaria What do you mean by "solution which really does not jQuery". jQuery is the most popular Javascript library and i dont't understand the reason behind it being not advisable.

Comment: I meant soluion which really does not "require" jQuery. having clarified that , let me explain. A) The OP(person asking the question) has not tagged jQuery so your solution is out of bound in that context. B) Using Jquery for a simple issue means the OVERHEAD of downloading the jQuery library for one simple task making your site slower. C) I had a 3rd reason. But i forgot it. Anyways the 2 reasons i gave are more than enough for my -1 explanation.

Comment: When you include jQuery library from any of the Cloud CDNs it is very likely that it is cached on the users browsers already, the overhead of downloading is not really a big problem.

Comment: Thats a good point you make. However for that to work. every site you visit must have the same reference. How can you make sure that every reference to a jQuery library will always be the same. However thats not the talking point. The issue is, why would you use a library which has thousands of function when you have a solution that can be done in 2 lines.